# What's wrong with the simplest Data-binding with WPF without using `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `DependencyProperty`

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I'm just been playing with Data Bindings in WPF (I'm new to all this) and the following code is the simplest implementation that I can get to work. Code below:

My question is:
Why would I need to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` and all the boilerplate code that comes with it or `DependencyProperty` etc when the simple below works just fine out of the box?
I'm trying to understand why the examples and answers on this site are far more complicated that the example below.

My XAML

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ConduitWidth, Mode = TwoWay}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding ConduitWidth, Mode = TwoWay}" />
```

My Code-behind

```
public partial class ConduitCapacityCalculator : UserControl
{

    ConduitCapacity conduitCapacity = new ConduitCapacity();
    public ConduitCapacityCalculator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = conduitCapacity;
        conduitCapacity.ConduitWidth = 10; //Just to check the textboxes update properly
    }
}
```

And my Class

```
public class ConduitCapacity
{
    private double _conduitWidth;

    public double ConduitWidth
    {
        get { return _conduitWidth; }
        set { _conduitWidth = value; } //add any conditions or Methods etc here
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to what is said in the answers, you should avoid private view models in controls. The UserControl should instead expose a dependency property ConduitWidth, which is bound in the control's XAML like `Text="{Binding ConduitWidth, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`. The control's DataContext must then not be set explicitly.

Comment: Please read my updated answer to learn how to enable TwoWay binding. After some discussion I decided to add more details to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Mode = TwoWay` is not true in your example.

Without any signalling (INotifyPropertyChanged) from the Source you are only getting OneWayToSource + OneTime modes.

To test this, add a button and make it do: `conduitCapacity.ConduitWidth = 100;`

See if you get that 100 in your Control.

Comment: You are indeed correct. The button does not change the UI as you suggested. After adding in the INotifyPropertyChanged and boilerplate code the button does work. What I don't get is, without the INotifyPropertyChanged, when I type a number in the first textbox, it will trigger setter, but how does the second textbox receive the updated value if it's acting with OneWayToSource + OneTime mode. This is what tricked me into thinking I didn't need the INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: You get 2 Binding objects that apparently trigger eachother. I'm not totally sure how that works. But there is no triggering from the DataContext (alone).

Answer (score 1):

Such a binding does work indeed, but will create a memory leak. The framework will create a static reference to the source object `ConduitCapacity` to observe it. Since static references are never eligible for the garbage collector, the static object reference will keep the object `ConduitCapacity` alive, preventing it from being collected. This also applies when binding to collections that do not implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

If you are concerned to avoid memory leaks, then the source of a data binding must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, `INotifyCollectionChanged` or the property must be a `DependencyProperty`.

`DependencyProperty` provides the best performance. This means when the source object is a `DependencyObject`, you should prefer to implement properties that are intended to be used as binding source as `DependencyProperty`.

#### Update:

**How data binding works when not following the `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `DependencyProperty` binding pattern and how to enable `TwoWay` binding using this method**

After some discussions in the comment section, I felt the need to update the question to explain the background a little bit more.

Combining the information provided by [Microsoft Docs: How Data Binding References are Resolved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-data-binding?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#how-data-binding-references-are-resolved) and the Microsoft Knowledge Base document
[KB 938416](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/938416),
we understand that WPF uses three methods to establish a data binding from a `DependencyProperty` (binding target) to any CLR object (binding source):

1. `TypeDescrtiptor` (component inspection)
2. `INotifyPropertyChanged`
3. `DependencyProperty`

The original question relates to method 1): creating a data binding to a source, that does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or a `DependencyProperty`. Therefore, the framework has to make use of the heavy `TypeDescriptor` to setup the binding and tracking of property changes.

From the KB 938416 document we learn that the binding engine will store a static reference to the obtained `PropertyDescriptor` (by using the `TypeDescriptor`). Since obtaining the `PropertyDescriptor` this way is very slow, the `PropertyDescriptor` reference is stored in a static `HashTable` (to avoid successive component inspection).

The framework uses this `PropertyDescriptor` to listen to property changes. Now, because the descriptor intance is stored in a static `HashTable`, it will never be eligible for garbage collection.
Static references or objects are generally never managed by the farbage collector.
Hence the memory leak, as the static reference will keep the source object alive for the lifetime of the application.

To unlock `TwoWay` binding, we have to explicitly enable the support in order to make the `PropertyDescriptor` be aware of property changes on the `Binding.Source`.
We can test this awareness by querying the `PropertyDescriptor.SupportsChangeEvents` property. It is `true` when:

1. We use `DependencyObject.SetValue` to modify the property (which means the property is also a `DependencyProperty`) or
2. The `Binding.Source` provides an event, that must comply with the following naming pattern: "[property_name]Changed"

This means, without an extra event, the binding to the plain CLR object can only be `OneTime` or `OneWayToSource`. Initialization from source to target will always work.

#### Example

**CLR object**
The binding source, that does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but still supports `TwoWay` binding.

```
class ClrObject
{
  public string TextProperty { get; set; }

  // Event to enable TwoWay data binding
  public event EventHandler TextPropertyChanged;

  protected virtual void OnTextPropertyChanged() 
    => this.TextPropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

This is what the WPF framework is doing:

```
// Simplified. Would use reflection and binding engine lookup table to retrieve the binding.
// Example references a TextBox control named "BindingTarget" for simplicity
Binding binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(this.BindingTarget, TextBox.TextProperty);

// Only observe Binding.Source when binding is TwoWay or OneWay
if (binding.Mode != BindingMode.OneWay 
  && binding.Mode != BindingMode.TwoWay)
{
  return;
}

object bindingSource = binding.Source ?? this.BindingTarget.DataContext;

// Use heavy TypeDescriptor inspection to obtain the object's PropertyDescriptors
PropertyDescriptorCollection descriptors = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(bindingSource);

foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in descriptors)
{
  if (descriptor.Name.Equals(binding.Path.Path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    && descriptor.SupportsChangeEvents)
  {
    // Add descriptor to static HashTable for faster lookup 
    // (e.g. in case for additional data bindings to this source object). 
    // TypeDescriptor is too slow

    // Attach a change delegate
    descriptor.AddValueChanged(bindingSource, UpdateTarget_OnSourcePropertyChanged);

    break;
  }
}
```

We can see why this way of data binding performs do bad. The`TypeDescriptor` is very slow. Additionally, the engine has to use more reflection to find the`TextPropertyChanged` event to initialize the `TwoWay` binding.

We can conclude, that even if it wasn't for the memory leak, we would avoid this solution and rather implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` on CLR objects or better implement properties as `DependencyProperty` (in case the source is a `DependencyObject`) to improve the application's performance significantly (an application usually defines hundreds of bindings).

Comment: Do you have a reference for that "static reference to the source object" ? This sounds very strange to me.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I believe that's what this page is referring to in the first "binding leak" section: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/09/04/fighting-common-wpf-memory-leaks-with-dotmemory/

Comment: @HenkHolterman [KB 938416](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/938416).

Comment: @StayOnTarget Thank you. This issue is officiallyregistered by Microsoft under [KB 938416](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/938416).

Comment: @BionicCode indeed, that's a better reference. Thanks

Comment: OK, I didn't know about this one. But one of the conditions is  _"Object X contains a direct reference or an indirect reference to the target of the data-binding operation."_ that does not seem to apply here. The example uses an ElementName binding where it does.

Comment: So I'm not convinced this is a problem for this use-case.

Comment: @HenkHolterman This is a simple example. The issue is related the way WPF establishes a binding of the source implements neither INotifyPropertyChanged nor a DependencyProperty. This is the official alternative to make data binding work even if the client code does not follow the pattern. It's a fallback or failsafe solution

Comment: @HenkHolterman [Microsoft Docs: How Data Binding References are Resolved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-data-binding?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#how-data-binding-references-are-resolved). The issue is related to creating a binding using the PropertyDescriptor (or TypeDescriptor).

Comment: @HenkHolterman From the KB link: _"Property P is accessed through a PropertyDescriptor object instead of a DependencyProperty object or a PropertyInfo object."_

Comment: The way I read the KB page all three conditons should hold. Bullet 2 should be rare. The jetbrains example is more like that on this page, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I posted a link to the Microsoft Docs that explains the three ways to establish a binding, where the first version meets the scenario of the OP. I have posted an official KB document that gives some insight that the PropertyDiscriptor way uses a "global table" to store references to Binding.Source object. Which makes sense in a way to improve performance as TypeDescriptor reflection does not come for free. Adding additional bindings. to the same object becomes faster after the initial one.

Comment: Because for fast look up the retrieved PropertyDiscriptor instance is stored in a static HashTable. There is only the TypeDescriptor way (aside the two other recommended patterns). So when you combine the information of both provided links, you can explain how the leak is created. This comes before the event handler delegate is combined with the ValueChlanged event delegate.

Comment: @BionicCode - So why does the TwoWay binding still not work?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Please read the _More Information_ section of the KB document. Also read the posted _How Data Binding References are resolved_  article. I have updated my answer to provide a short example and explanation why it does not work and  how to enable TwoWay binding.

Answer (score 0):

This is not wrong. The reason for the INotifyPropertyChanged is so your UI updates when you change your class.

For Example, if you decide to update conduitCapacity later your UI would still display the old Value. [INotifyPropertChanged Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-5.0)

The reason for the DepedencyProperties is that you can extend your UserControl with it let's say you want to use your Usercontrol in your MainWindow and give it some Property like MaximumConduitWidth. Than you would do something like this:

```
     public double MaximumConduitWidth
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MaximumConduitWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaximumConduitWidthProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumConduitWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MaximumConduitWidth", typeof(double), typeof(ConduitCapacityCalculator), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

And then you could write this in your MainWindow.xaml

```
<ConduitCapacityCalculator MaximumConduitWidth=10/>
```

[Dependency Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)